# stuck mysql find last working day in previous month

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask you that i want to find last working day in previous month in MYSQL.

How to do that ?

this code find last day previous month as the following:

```
LAST_DAY(Now()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Result that i need as below:

Current Month= 2013-07-01====> Results should be 2013-06-28

Current Month= 2013-06-06====> Results should be 2013-05-31

How to find last working day in previous month ?

Regards

Comment: I think you must find this is in backend, not in database. What happen for 31 December here in Bulgaria is holiday day now working day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an example of what I thought of:

```
LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) -
INTERVAL (CASE WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
          WHEN 5 THEN 1
          WHEN 6 THEN 2
          ELSE 0 END) DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way of writing this (I'd be surprised if there wasn't), but Gumbo's solution might look like this...

Note I've used `@dt` for testing. You could just substitute `CURDATE()` in your script.

```
 SET @dt = '2012-07-01'; -- Last day of the previous month (June 2012) was a Saturday

 SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 2 DAY 
        WHEN 7 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        ELSE LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        END x;
 +------------+
 | x          |
 +------------+
 | 2012-06-29 | -- Friday 29th 
 +------------+


 SET @dt = '2012-08-01'; -- Last day of the previous month (July 2012) was a Tuesday

 SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 2 DAY 
        WHEN 7 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        ELSE LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        END x;
 +------------+
 | x          |
 +------------+
 | 2012-07-31 | -- Tuesday 31st
 +------------+

 SET @dt = '2012-10-01'; -- Last day of the previous month (September 2012) was a Sunday

 SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 2 DAY 
        WHEN 7 THEN LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)-INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        ELSE LAST_DAY(@dt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        END x;
 +------------+
 | x          |
 +------------+
 | 2012-09-28 | -- Friday 28th 
 +------------+
```

Another way is to build a calendar table of all dates. Ignoring public holidays, the first and last working days of the month then are simply the min and max weekdays of the month.

Although, there is an argument that goes 'so why not just figure this bit out in your application code'!

Comment: i don't think about holiday, i want to skip Saturday and Sunday if met it.

Comment: I know. Hence my solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get last working date you have to follow following steps : 
1. first of all get last date of last month .
2.check whether it is working day or not by weekday function . if it is sunday then subtract 2 from lastdate , if it is saturday then subtract 1 from lastdate otherwise do not change anything .

we can do this thing by case statement . check following query . it will really works :

```
SELECT 
CASE WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-' , MONTH(CURDATE())-1 ,'-' , 1))) 
WHEN 6 
  THEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-' , MONTH(CURDATE())-1 ,'-' , 1)),INTERVAL -2 DAY)
WHEN 5
  THEN DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-' , MONTH(CURDATE())-1 ,'-' , 1)),INTERVAL - 1 DAY) 
ELSE 
  LAST_DAY(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-' , MONTH(CURDATE())-1 ,'-' , 1)) END;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/15940

Comment: @Dnakk Jam did this query help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SET @lastworkingday = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) DAY);

// If saturday, take it back one day
IF DAYOFWEEK(@lastworkingday) = 7 
    THEN @lastworkingday := DATE_SUB(@lastworkingday, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
// If sunday, take it back two days
ELSE IF DAYOFWEEK(@lastworkingday) = 1
    THEN @lastworkingday := DATE_SUB(@lastworkingday, INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Comment: Hence 'something like'. It might not have perfect syntax.

Answer (score -2):

if you subtract the day of current month then you will get the last day of previous month

```
(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) DAY))
```

For example, on the 12th of the month if we  subtract 12 days,then well get the the last day of the previous month:

Comment: Dear i need last working of previous month not last day in previous month.

Comment: Current Month= 2013-07-01====> Results should be 2013-06-28
Current Month= 2013-06-06====> Results should be 2013-05-31

Comment: how it is be sure that your 2013-06-28 is the last date.

Comment: it should be store in some field in your database.

Comment: i dont want to store in database.

Comment: Check the day of the week of the last day of the month and subtract 1 day if it’s a saturday and two if it’s a sunday.

Comment: can give me example coding?